# What's the difference between click event handler and ngClick directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="./angular-1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        function scopeReady(s) {
            document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                alert(s.items);
                s.btnClick();
                alert(s.items);
            });
        }

        function ctrl($scope) {
            $scope.items = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
            $scope.btnClick = function() {
                $scope.items.push("one more");
            };
            scopeReady($scope);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
<li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
<button id="btn">Event Handler</button>
<button ng-click="btnClick()">Angular ngClick</button>
</body>
</html>
```

As what the code snippet shows, why the click of the first button does not trigger update of DOM? Both ng-click and the event handler invokes the same function to proceed. It's quiet confusing to me.

Answer (score 4):

Event handlers run "outside" of Angular, so Angular doesn't know about the change to `items`, so the ng-repeat does not re-render.  Call `s.$apply()` to cause Angular to run a [digest cycle](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime), which will update your view.

With ng-click, `scope.$apply()` is called automatically.